# Changing the dir errors and hunchentoot - Dir not found?

Tags: common-lisp, sbcl

I use a macro called `use-db` and `change-to-path` in a lot of my projects.

```lisp
(defmacro use-db (db project-name &body query)
  `(progn
     (change-to-path ,project-name)
     (clsql:connect ,db :database-type :sqlite3)
     (unwind-protect (progn ,@query)
       (clsql:disconnect :database ,db))))

(defmacro change-to-path (project-name)
  `(uiop:chdir (merge-pathnames (write-to-string ,project-name) "/Users/vince/quicklisp/local-projects/")))
```

As you can see, change to path changes the repl dir. Then use-db reads the sqlite db from the root of the project folder. This works fine.

However, when I try to read a db as part of a route (`easy-routes` + `hunchentoot`):

```lisp
(defroute test-file ("/results" :method :post)
    ()
  (get-one-col-as-list-db #'first "firstname"))


(defun get-one-col-as-list-db (fn tablename)
  (ki:use-db "new.db" 'custom-sender
    (mapcar fn
        (clsql:query
         (concatenate 'string "Select * from " tablename)))))
```

I get the following error:

`Error in SB-POSIX:CHDIR: No such file or directory (2)`

without using the `change-to-path` macro, `clsql` function would note find the database.

Is there a better way to use sqlite (from the file system) and manage the pathing for specific db files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the current working directory, temporarily, use `uiop:with-current-directory`:

```lisp
(uiop:with-current-directory ("/tmp/")
   (uiop:getcwd))
```

(edit) `chdir` has a side effect: it effectively changes the current working directory (`uiop:getcwd),` while `with-current-directory` doesn't, or it does but only temporarily for the code under it. For your sanity you want to avoid `chdir`'s side effets (or I do, I want to work at a project root). It could have an effect on bare-bones Hunchentoot, if it looks at a `www/` directory under the project root, but in your case I'm not sure.

---

Your `use-db` mimics a well-known pattern: get a resource, and be sure to release it in case of errors. These macros are often named "with-something", just like "with-current-directory". Does CLSQL have such a macro? It does: [with-database](https://clsql.kpe.io/manual/with-database.html).

---

Why is your `change-to-path` a macro? It can be a function that concatenates strings and calls `chdir`.

Inside `use-db`, "project-name" is an unknown variable. Look at the compiler warnings:

```
; caught WARNING:
;   undefined variable: COMMON-LISP-USER::PROJECT-NAME
```

How do you use the two anyways?

> Error in SB-POSIX:CHDIR: No such file or directory (2) […] without using the change-to-path macro

what is the directory it tries to go to? You'd have a tip on how things are not working.

Comment: Sorry, i copied in the wrong version. `project-name is a macro param` - updated

Comment: The error from the hunchetoot route is that there is no directory. But this directory already works, except with hunchentoot. The path is "/Users/vince/quicklisp/local-projects/project-name/new.db" <--- the macro `use-db` has no issue finding this file other than with hunchentoot + easy routes

Comment: OK… I'd need more details to reason about Hunchentoot. Try with a full path to the DB, without `chdir`? Does using `with-current-directory` bring the same issue?

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you. I have been strugging with this issue for some time and using `with-current-directory` is the solution I have been looking for. I am not sure why this worked, maybe you can shed some light on the difference between `chdir` and `with-current-directory`

Comment: `chdir` has a side effect: it effectively changes the current working directory (`uiop:getcwd`), while `with-current-directory` doesn't, or it does but only temporarily for the code under it. For your sanity you want to avoid `chdir`'s side effets (or I do, I want to work at a project root). It could have an effect on bare-bones Hunchentoot, if it looks at a `www/` directory under the project root, but in your case I'm not sure.

Comment: You should add this as an answer, this is very useful for people who are not aware.

Answer (score 1):

I try to never rely on the process working directory, because from Common Lisp I am much happier using `*default-pathname-defaults*` (no side effects!). This is a special variable with a long name, and what I want is to use `merge-pathnames` in most of the cases, so I have this macro:

```
(defmacro with-path (pathname &body body)
  `(let ((*default-pathname-defaults* (merge-pathnames ,pathname)))
     ,@body))
```

It is just a local binding of a special variable so unwinding is trivial, and it comes with all the benefits of CL pathnames (and some of its drawbacks but that's fine).
On the Posix side of things, programs want a native namestring so I also use this a lot:

```
(defun fullname (pathname)
  (osicat:native-namestring (merge-pathnames pathname)))
```

I do also have a concept of projects in my environment so it looks as follows. Note that I try to carry the special variable until the last moment, until it needs to be given to other processes, like:

```
(within-project projects:my-project
  (with-path "build/"
    (run "make")))
```

Here `run` grabs the current `*default-pathname-defaults*` for its `:directory` argument (using `sb-ext:run-program` but this is a detail).

Since it is a pathname, some components can be wild too, if that makes sense in your use case. For example, you can avoid giving a `".db"` suffix if you prefer:

```
(defmacro using-db ((name db) &body body)
  `(with-path #P"*.db"
     (with-database (,name (list (fullname ,db)) :database-type :sqlite3)
       ,@body)))
```

For example, here I enter the `"/tmp/"` directory and open database `"test.db"`:

```
(with-path "/tmp/"
  (using-db (database "test")
    database)))

#<CLSQL-SQLITE3:SQLITE3-DATABASE /tmp/test.db CLOSED {100DD6CE63}>
```

---

Edit: with respect to the following code:

```
(uiop:chdir
  (merge-pathnames (write-to-string project-name)
    "/Users/vince/quicklisp/local-projects/")))
```

Note that you can use ASDF to access files relative to systems:

```
(asdf:system-relative-pathname :cl-ppcre "ppcre.lisp")
#P"..../quicklisp/software/cl-ppcre-20220220-git/ppcre.lisp"
```

Comment: When you use `asdf:system-relative-pathname` in the repl, what is it reletive too? I find my repl location to always be random locations (like my .emacs dir).

Comment: Each process has a current directory, that's what getcwd returns and typically it is the directory from which you started the lisp interpreter; for asdf it is relative to the .asd file that defined the system, so e.g. in your quicklisp/local-projects/ directory